# QueryWrapperFilter is deprecated in Filter

Tags: hibernate-search

I'm trying to create a Numeric Filter but I can't return a NumericRangeQuery with my factory because I get:

```
NumericRangeQuery cannot be cast to org.apache.lucene.search.Filter
```

So I had to wrap it in a `QueryWrapperFilter` but it's now deprecated. In the [docs](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/QueryWrapperFilter.html) it says to use a `BooleanQuery` with `Occur.FILTER` but I can't get an instance of a `QueryBuilder` inside my filter factory and the constructor `BooleanQuery()` is also deprecated, what should I do?

This is my working code so far:

```
public class ConStockFilterFactory {

  @Factory
  public Query getFilter() {
    return new QueryWrapperFilter(NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("stock", 0, Integer.MAX_VALUE, false, true));
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the deprecated `Filter`s for now because we cannot change the API/SPI in Search 5.x.

We will get rid of the deprecated `Filter` dependency in the upcoming Search 6.